# Access an AngularJS app running on a Grunt-Proxy server inside a VM from the host

Tags: proxy, angularjs, gruntjs

In our development environment we have Ubuntu VMs running on a Windows 7 host.  We found that if we change the Gruntfile's "connect.options.hostname" to '0.0.0.0' we can hit our Angular app running in the VM from Internet Explorer in the host.

In order to avoid a cross-domain error when we hit some web services from Angular, we setup a Grunt-Proxy server.  This works fine in the VM.  From the host, any time the app tries to hit a web service it fails (since it's not on the proxy port) trying to access a server on port 9000 (the server is running on port 8888). From the host when I try to access the App on the proxy port (8050) I just get a 404 error - I'm not really sure how to proceed with this.

My proxy is setup as follows in the Gruntfile:

```
proxy: {
  proxy1: {
    options: {
      port : 8050,
      host : 'localhost',
      router : {
        'localhost/rest/*' : 'localhost:8888',
        'localhost' : 'localhost:9000'
      }
    }
  }
},
```

I tried playing with some of these settings but haven't had any luck. Any help would be appreciated.